# How do I notify when the screen is resizing in angualrjs

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a webpage with three sections and when I click a button I am changing the width of each sections based on screen width. After I click the button  if I resize the screen the three sections adjust based on current screen size. I am trying to get notification when screen size changing.
Here is my html code.

```
<div class="minbutton" ng-click="minimize()">
                <div  ng-if="toggles">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i>
                </div>
                <div ng-if="!toggles">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
                </div>
      </div>
```

Here is my controller code.

```
$scope.minimize= function(){
                var width =$(window).width();                                
                if($scope.toggles=== true){         
                   $(".section1").attr('style','width:14%');
                   $(".section2").attr('style','width:26%');
                   $(".section2").attr('style','left:14%');
                   $(".section3").attr('style','left:40%');
                   $(".section3").attr('style','width:60%')
                   $scope.toggles = true;
                } else {
                    section1Left = 56;
                    leftSection = width - 56;
                    section2Width=Math.round( leftSection * 0.30);
                    section3Left = section2Width + 56;
                    section3Width = Math.round(leftSection *0.70);
                    $(".section1").css("cssText","width:56px !important;");       
                    $('.section2').css({left:section1Left,width:section2Width});
                    $('.section3').css({left:section3Left,width:section3Width}):
                    $scope.toggles = false;
                }
            };
```

when I click minimize I am fixing first section and adjusting rest of the width for 2 sections.when the screen resizing I want to notify and get the current screen width and I am trying adjust the sections with the current width. How do I notify when screen resizing?

Answer (score 1):

Angular is not the answer. This is no special tools in angular for this. But you still can use JS or JQuery, like this
[Jquery resize](https://api.jquery.com/resize/)

Comment: Mark pls as answer if it was helpfull enough